# Categories is not showing in custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have registered a custom post type as follows:

```
//Register Custom Post Type Services
register_post_type('services', array(
    'labels'              => array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Services', 'Post Type General Name', 'fk' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Service', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'fk' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Services', 'fk' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Service', 'fk' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Services', 'fk' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Service', 'fk' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Service', 'fk' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'fk' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Service', 'fk' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Service', 'fk' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Service', 'fk' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'fk' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'fk' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Service' ),
    ),


    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
    // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy.
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'categories' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 20,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'show_in_rest'        => true,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-megaphone',
    'query_var'           => true,
    'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'services' ),

));
```

Here, I have just used categories as the taxonomy, but it is not showing the options to select categories while trying to create one of the services.

I don't need any custom categories, just regular categories options would be fine. By the way, before the line for `taxonomy` was commented and I added that later only.

Comment: Did you create a custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can use this code:**

//Register Custom Post Type Services
    register_post_type('services', array(
        'labels'              => array(
            'name'                => _x( 'Services', 'Post Type General Name', 'fk' ),
            'singular_name'       => _x( 'Service', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'fk' ),
            'menu_name'           => __( 'Services', 'fk' ),
            'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Service', 'fk' ),
            'all_items'           => __( 'All Services', 'fk' ),
            'view_item'           => __( 'View Service', 'fk' ),
            'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Service', 'fk' ),
            'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'fk' ),
            'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Service', 'fk' ),
            'update_item'         => __( 'Update Service', 'fk' ),
            'search_items'        => __( 'Search Service', 'fk' ),
            'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'fk' ),
            'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'fk' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Service' ),
        ),
    
    
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy.
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'categories' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 20,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'show_in_rest'        => true,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-megaphone',
        'query_var'           => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'services' ),
    
    ));
    
    function custom_tax() {
    
        $labels = array(
            'name'                       => 'Categories',
            'singular_name'              => 'Categories',
            'menu_name'                  => 'Categories',
            'all_items'                  => 'All Items',
            'parent_item'                => 'Parent Item',
            'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Item:',
            'new_item_name'              => 'New Item Name',
            'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Genre',
            'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Item',
            'update_item'                => 'Update Item',
            'view_item'                  => 'View Item',
            'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate items with commas',
            'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove items',
            'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used',
            'popular_items'              => 'Popular Items',
            'search_items'               => 'Search Items',
            'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
            'no_terms'                   => 'No items',
            'items_list'                 => 'Items list',
            'items_list_navigation'      => 'Items list navigation',
        );
            $args = array(
            'labels'                     => $labels,
            'hierarchical'               => true,
            'public'                     => true,
            'show_ui'                    => true,
            'show_admin_column'          => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
            'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'custom_tax', array( 'services' ), $args );
    
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'custom_tax', 0 );
```